# Google Maps mobile browser - forms in info window not clickable?

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile, maps

I'm having an issue being able to focus on any form input that's within an info window in a google maps application I'm developing that needs to be bother accessible with a typical browser and mobile browser via website.

So, in a typical pc browser, when an info pops up, and I populate it's content with a form, it functions as it should. But the same thing on a mobile browser, I am unable to click on the fields of the form within the info window at all?

Any ideas? I still have no idea what the problem is after extensive fiddling. I originally thought it was a z-index issue or something along those lines, but no luck!

Comment: Some code, or preferably a URL to stuff you've tried, would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem and solved it by stopping event propagation on mousedown events.  Using jQuery this amounts to:

```
div.mousedown(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```